# Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid - AWS Lambda Trigger Schedule

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to configure a trigger that runs on the first Wednesday of every month, but I keep getting the following error

> Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid

Here's my crod expression. Any idea on whats wrong with it?

```
rate(30 days), cron (0 12 *  *  WED *  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. here's the correct cron expression for anyone who's interested

```
cron(0 12 ? * 4#1 *)
```